# Correct way to use the word "respectively"

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I have the following sentence:

> Moreover, we use adjectives 'Borel' and 'finite' if, respectively, a measure is defined on the Borel sigma-algebra and it has finite values only.

Usually I put 'respectively' at the end of the sentence. But in the above sentence it does not sound good together with 'only'.

Is the sentence correct in this form?

Comment: There does not seem to be any need for "respectively" in the sentence — its meaning is clear enough without it.

Comment: What I meant in this sentence is that we can have in fact three possibilities:
1. "finite measure"
2. "Borel measure"
3. "finite Borel measure"
Where the last one is just a conjunction of two other conditions. 

If my sentence really has the meaning I described above, then I will remove 'respectively'. But I am not quite sure if it has the same meaning without this word.

Comment: What @Weather Vane said. But I might also consider changing both instances of ***and*** to ***and/or*** to make it more obvious which elements are being paired up (whether singly or together in any given instance).